# how many banks are currently rated B+ or above and when was the last time (dateindex) that they had been below

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

[image]

[image]

I have these two tables and im trying to get the dateindex of the last time that the company was rated below a B+. dateindex=19941 which means 1994 quarter 1

This selects all the companies that have B+ or above in q2 2020

```
SELECT DISTINCT mr.name, mc.rating, mr.DateIndex 
FROM [Model].[rating]mc inner join [Model].[RawHist]mr 
ON mc.BankId=mr.BankId
WHERE mc.Rating in ('A+','A','A-','B+') AND mr.DateIndex in('20202')
```

And it yields the following

[image]

How can I add the dateindex the last time it was below B+. so it would have those three fields and two more fields one with the last grade below b+ and its date index for 5 total fields.

This is what i have so far with the results
[image]
[image]

Its giving me way to many rows.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Why are you using `select distinct`?

Comment: just need to add two more fields with the last dateindex when it was below b+ and the that grade

Comment: I used distinct because it was spitting out a lot of duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have these two tables and im trying to get the dateindex of the last time that the company was rated below a B+.

This sounds like aggregation:

```
SELECT mr.name, MAX(mr.DateIndex)
FROM [Model].[rating] mc JOIN
     [Model].[RawHist]mr 
     ON mc.BankId = mr.BankId
WHERE mc.Rating NOT IN ('A+', 'A', 'A-','B+') 
GROUP BY mr.name;
```

This assumes that "less than B+" means that it is not one of the listed ratings.